# How to move all the values in a column to a new column in psql

Tags: psql

Here is my table structure:

```
Table name:Items
--------------------------------------------------------------
 id   | category_id |  name                |  alt_name
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1   | 1            |  Cochin State Manual |  Cochin
 2   | 1            |  Kuttavum Shikshayum |  Kuttavum
 2   | 1            |  Rajarshi            |  Rajarshihgfh
```

Here I need to move the all values of the alt_name column to a new column called temp.After that move all the values in the name column to alt_name column.In which name and alt_name are string type.The new column temp also a string field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to check the type of the `alt_name` column to be able to make `temp` the correct type and length to fit the data;

```
\d+ Items
```

For example, if `alt_name` is a `VARCHAR(64)`;

```
-- Add the column
ALTER TABLE Items ADD COLUMN temp VARCHAR(64);

-- Copy alt_name to temp
UPDATE Items SET temp = alt_name;

-- Copy name to alt_name
UPDATE Items SET alt_name = name;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/415f3/2).

And as always, always back up your data before running potentially destructive queries from random people on the Internet.

Comment: temp column is not exist

Comment: @geethujoseph Then you'll need to add the type of alt_name to your question (for example `VARCHAR(64)`) so that `temp` can be created with the correct type and not truncate your data.

Comment: I have included the type of columns

Comment: @geethujoseph That's not quite enough info, but I updated the answer on how to get the info you need to do the operation.